Someone help me with create_android_keystore and create_android_playintegrity
I'm making a request to Instagram's android api, I'm having issues with create_android_playintegrity and create_android_keystore. Specifically as follows:

with app_scoped_id can i generate them with uuid v4?
How can I generate the corresponding key_hash value?
create_android_keystore

I tried changing some values ​​but the result is still "ok". but when I use challenge_nonce to make a post request to om.bloks.www.bloks.caa.reg.create.account.async I get status code 429
I need the above 2 values ​​because com.bloks.www.bloks.caa.reg.create.account.async requires them. without X-Ig-Attest-Params in the header, my tool can only run at most 1 thread. with 2 or more threads, Instagram always returns status code 429

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
